# OpenSubKey() in Windows 11

Tags: powershell, registry, windows-11

once upon a time I used this snippet of code to open a registry key.

```
$Path='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall' 
$Key='Autodesk Revit 2019'
$localMachineHive = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, 0)
$localMachineHive.OpenSubKey("$Path\$Key")
```

That was in Windows 10, and I am pretty sure early builds of Windows 11. I am now trying it again with a current build of Windows 11, and getting nothing. Has something changed, or am I missing something? I have tried various UAC levels, and that doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: Did you install Audodesk Revit 2019 in your new Windows 11 installation?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that the path is taken right out of the registry. And I have tried multiple keys.

Comment: My best guess is that you're actually looking in two different places - eg. either you grabbed it from a 32-bit view in regedit and are now querying from a 64-bit PowerShell process, or vice versa

Comment: But, I copied the entire path from the registry, so I am SURE the path exists. Further, `$localMachineHive` seems to be empty, and it shouldn't be. It feels like Microsoft @%#%$ed something up in Windows 11, which wouldn't be a surprise. But since me screwing something up wouldn't be a surprise either... :)

Comment: Wait, am I missing something. Definitely a 64 bit process, but I have always been able to access 32 bit install keys via `Wow6432Node*` node. In this case it's a 64 bit program, but this has me wondering if I am going to have problems given how much of Autodesk's garbage is still 32 bit all these years later. They really are just rubbish.